# Using wordpress menu outside wordpress enviorenment

Tags: wordpress, menu, phpbb

Im trying to display my dynamic wordpress menu in the header of phpbb.

How do I include the wordpress header? What files should be included in order to display the autogenerated menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to implement the JSON plugin which exports various WP variables on command:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/